# Jekyll Converters::Scss build issue: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs

Tags: javascript, error-handling, jekyll, github-pages

I keep getting this error when I try to publish a site to GitHub pages.

```
 Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
19
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

When I try to change the folder to root, it publishes the readme.md file. When I change it to doc, I get this error.

The file runs fine locally. I don't know what the problem is. I searched online but did not find a solution that helps. Any help works.

The error is on my main branch when I try to publish it.

Links to the repo and the error on GitHub:

- https://github.com/Rsmdo/dadport2
- https://github.com/Rsmdo/dadport2/tree/main

[image]

I tried making a new repo but this did not solve the issue, also I went through the code to see if there were any parsing errors but there were none.

Comment: Hmm, you have merge conflicts in main since your 2nd commit (see <<<<<, =====, and >>>>> lines in https://github.com/Rsmdo/dadport2/commit/c7709c4713c743234c8a7d924a3c493d5416b1b7). It doesn't seem to be a Jekyll but a React project. Maybe you mixed up and used the wrong GH action workflow(s).

Comment: Jekyll does not appear to be installed in this repo. How do you run this locally? Where do you change the path to docs. To which path does it relate?

Answer (score 0):

https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/cannot-deploy-site-via-github/6883/11 says that "Jekyll can’t find the files the theme uses". The page also suggests using root instead of docs or any folder.

There are options to set the directory where Jekyll writes files to and reads file from, for example: `bundle exec jekyll s -s /docs`, which leads to errors in my case due to the non-existing path based on the root path (the path can also be relative I guess).

See `Source: /docs`, the other path do not show the docs path though.

```
PS C:\Users\User\usr.github.io> bundle exec jekyll s -s /docs
Configuration file: none
            Source: /docs
       Destination: C:/Users/User/usr.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
Error reading file C:/Users/User/usr.github.io/_layouts/archive.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/docs/Users/User/usr.github.io/_layouts/archive.html
```

This may help:

- https://jekyll.one/pages/public/manuals/jekyll/user_guide/configuration/
- https://github.com/burtlo/jekyll-core/blob/master/site/docs/configuration.md